# Based on Boolean value, setup a conditional activity - without using the IF ACTIVITY

Tags: conditional-statements, boolean, azure-data-factory

I am trying to setup my pipeline such that it uses a condition based on the boolean value and if it is true to continue in a direction of the pipeline, if it is false to continue in another direction.

if it true I want it to continue the top of the pipeline... Set Folder Path etc and if is false to just end the pipeline with the failed slack notification. I want to achieve this without using the IF condition activity as it will mean I will have to integrate the whole continuation of the pipeline within the condition so if this can be achieved in another means, that would be perfect.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to achieve this without using the IF condition activity.

First, I took a simple set variable to get Boolean response.

[image]

To achieve this scenario, you have to take one set variable activity with **demo** variable with `string` type and `@if(variables('bool'),'true',0)` so if value of variable is **true** then it will assign **string value true to variable** and if the value of variable is false it will assign `0`  integer value to it and activity will fail.

[image]

On Succeed you can call activities to run which on **true** response.

[image]

On Failure you can call activities to run which on **false** response.

[image]

Comment: Great job, thank you for the answer and insight here!